# Setup Entity Framework 6 with Mysql - Code first

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to setup a existing project to use Entity Framework. I have never used it before and want to learn it on a personal project.

I have a solution with many projects, all related. Login is where I wanna do querys. Model is where the model is. Main is where the program starts.

I have installed EntityFramework onto MySolution.Model.

This is the app.config for Model:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ALDatabaseContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=aldatabase;uid=root;password=root"/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
<providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

My context is very simple

```
public class ALDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

But when I call context from Login I get an exception:

> Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

What I am missing?

Comment: Did you use Entity framework wizard ?

Comment: Mm nop, I have installed entity framework using Nuget and configured as mysql page says.

Comment: Did you added a reference to `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6`? Make sure is copied to the `bin` folder.

Comment: I have tried adding all, also installing EF and Mysql.Data on Login project without results.

I can make querys on Model projects, works, but when I want to use it in another project it throws the exception that I mention on the post.

I don't know what I have to do in the Login project to get it working..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get it working (but I don't like the solution).

I have added this to the app.config of Main (the entry point of my solution):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ALDatabaseContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=aldatabase;uid=root;password=root" />
</connectionStrings>



<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
</providers>


</entityFramework>


<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

And also referenced all dlls of Model (Entity framework related dll and Mysql dlls) at Login and Main projects.